# Python configparser: Copy comments from input file

Tags: python, configparser

I'm using configparser and Python 3.3 to create a script which makes some small modifications to config files. These config files often contain commented-out lines, like so:

```
[Section]
Value1=Foo
;Very important comment
;Another very important comment
Value2=Bar
```

Understandably, Python strips these out when it writes the new version of the config file, but that's something of a problem. Is there any way to copy the comments into the new config file? (Unfortunately, order is also important. Thanks to the OrderedDict, the order of config options is maintained properly, but the order of comments will need to be maintained as well, which hopefully will not be an issue.)

Thanks!

Comment: You might want to have a look at the [cfgparse](http://cfgparse.sourceforge.net/) module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple trick/workaround: Instead of a comment, put `REM_x=` in front to turn the comment into an option (which your code will ignore):

```
[Section]
Value1=Foo
REM_1=Very important comment
REM_2=Another very important comment
REM_Value2=Bar
Value2=Baz
```

Comment: So what I need to do is replace all the `;` characters and then change them back later? Also, why did you add `REM_` to `Value2` in your answer?

Comment: Changing the `;` characters would work but why bother? Create the config with comments as config options and leave them that way. The last example was to demonstrate how you can comment out normal options.

Comment: The issue is that I didn't create these files, I need to alter files which already exist.

Comment: Ah. In that case, replacing the `;` with `REM_` + a number + `=` should work in many cases (it'll fail for `key=value # comment`)

Comment: What's the best way to remove the `REM_`s later?

Comment: Read the whole file as a string and do the usual search&replace.